# how to concatenate an indefinite number of strings without using string.h

Tags: c

So I have a `char **args`, but I want to concatenate all the strings into a single `char *newArgs` without using `string.h`.

Anyone know a good way to do this?

Comment: Do you know how many args there are, or is there some other way of terminating?

Comment: I can figure out how many there are. I also know that each individual string is null terminated

Comment: You can first solve the problem using `string.h` functions and then implement your own replacement versions of those functions.

Answer (score 5):

This is actually one of the few cases where disregarding the standard implementation (string.h) and building a concatenating function of your own gets you better results. See [Joel's fantastic article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html) that discusses this topic.

But back to your question: you need to do two passes through the strings in `args`. On the first pass you sum the lengths of the strings (don't forget null terminator!). Now that you have the length of the resulting string you can allocate a buffer for `newArgs`. On the other pass you copy the contents from `args` to `newArgs`.